# Load dynamic content from php on submitting a form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have created a page "index.php" with a lot of divs and I need to refresh only one of the divs when the form is submitted.

This div loads the content from chat_window.php which is as follows:

```
<div id="chatbox">
    <?php echo $res; ?>
</div>  

<!-- Chat user input form-->
<?php echo $formchat; ?>
```

chat_window.php uses dynamic content - `$res` and `$formchat` from chat.php.
Everytime I post the form the content of $res and $formchat is modified and I need to reflect the same in my page which loads chat_window.php.

I used AJAX and jQuery to do the same as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var name = $("input#chat").val();
        var dataString = "chat="+ name;

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "programo/bot/chat.php",  
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {  
            }  
        });  

        $("#chatwrapper").load(chat_window.php);

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

The index.php has a div to show the chat_window as follows:

```
<!-- Chat window-->
<div id="chatwrapper"> 
    <?php include ("chat_window.php"); ?>
</div>
```

As per my analysis, when I post the form, $res and $formchat are getting updated in the php. But when I load the chat_window.php, it doesnot loads the modified values. It rather loads the initial static values. 
(Please dont suggest `setInterval()` as I dont want to refresh the page automatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my work done. Though I used another way of doing it.

What I have understood after few days of R&D is that, when we submit the form to a php, the request is sent with input params. When your php file processes this request, it might be updating some global variables. It completes processing the request and returns the control back to the calling index.php page.

The important thing to notice is:
The variable updates made while processing the form submit request do not persist after the control is returned. The global php variables will only get updated when the page gets refreshed.

So, if there is a strict requirement to avoid page refresh, collect the processed data from the php in some output string and pass it back to index.php like this:

```
$responseString = $res . "|" . $formchat; 
echo $responseString;
```

The success parameter of .ajax will receive this output and accordingly you can update your chat window or any other form.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is non-blocking, so it means that the interpreter does not wait for jobs to complete before processing the next one.

In your code, `$("#chatwrapper").load('chat_window.php');` is being called pretty much before the ajax request above it completes. You will need to use the ajax success event to call the reload.

Try:

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "programo/bot/chat.php",  
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {  
     $("#chatwrapper").load('chat_window.php');
  }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have even tried the above. Unfortunately, it doesnot work. :(

Comment: are there any Javascript errors showing up? Try using Firebug to see the response from the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `.load()` statement into the ajax success handler:

```
 $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "programo/bot/chat.php",  
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {  
       $("#chatwrapper").load("chat_window.php");
  }  

});
```

The `$.ajax()` call is *asynchronous,* which means that execution does not pause waiting for the response, rather, it moves on directly to the `.load()` call. (Which is also asynchronous, so really you've no guarantee about the order the response from each call will come in unless you don't make the second call until the first one finishes.)

Comment: It should work (aside from the missing quotation marks that I just added, which were missing in your question too). Are you sure it's reloading the initial values as compared to doing nothing at all?

Comment: I checked it after adding the quotations. But no success. Though the request is being processed (which i checked using alerts), but "chat_window.php" doesnot gets the refreshed value of $res.